# Rails SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: index 'index_users_on_reset_password_token'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Делаю регистрацию с devise

Добавил поле username для User. Для авторизации использую email + pwd.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys:[:username])
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :username, presence: true
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :registerable,
     :rememberable, 
     :trackable, 
     :validatable
end

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170228132910) do
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",               default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "username",            default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",       default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index [nil], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Первый пользователь зарагистрировался нормально, на втором получаю ошибку

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in
>   Devise::RegistrationsController#create SQLite3::ConstraintException:
>   UNIQUE constraint failed: index 'index_users_on_reset_password_token':
>   INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "username",
>   "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Что там ни так с index_users_on_reset_password_token ?

Добавил миграцию

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      # Registrable
      t.string :username,           null: false, default: ""

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: `t.index [nil]` -- што? Как это вышло? Покажите миграцию, это выдавшую.

Comment: А кто у вас тут primary key?

Comment: @vp_arth неявный, суррогатный `id` типа `integer` с автоинкрементом. Rails использует такой по умолчанию.

Comment: Добавил миграцию

Comment: А где поле? `reset_password_token`

Comment: Это типа не баг, а фича? Способ сделать таблицу с одной строкой)

Comment: Видимо т.к. он относится к :recoverable а я его не предусматриваю, то его и нет.

Comment: @SergeiR тогда и индекса соответствующего быть не должно. Удивительно, что миграция вообще прошла.

Comment: Вариант сделать миграцию без индекса и накатить по новой?

Comment: @SergeiR если эта миграция уже ушла на сервер, то нет, не вариант, надо делать новую, удаляющую только этот индекс. Но куда более важный вопрос, что это за индекс, какое у него определение, почему Rails его так странно сдампил.

Comment: На этот вопрос я вряд ли отвечу, 4 день как руби вижу в живую )

Comment: @D-side А вы оформите ваш ответ, он собственно ответом и является. Теперь все работает после удаления t.index [nil], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token"

Comment: Это надо смотреть скорее в SQLite, а не в руби, но это я могу сам проверить, ок :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Об этом сообщали в баг-трекер Rails ([#27782](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27782)) и это проблема в SQLite:

> SQLite has a (mis-)feature that double-quoted names that cannot be
>   resolved to a table or column name are treated as strings.  This was a
>   very early design decision, made long before SQLite went viral and
>   found itself running in everything device on the planet, and was
>   intended to make SQLite more compatible with MySQL, which at the time
>   was the most widely deployed database engine in the world.  I regret
>   that choice now, but I cannot undo it without breaking backwards
>   compatibility.
>
> *— D. Richard Hipp, создатель SQLite*

По-русски:

> У SQLite есть (упоротая) особенность: идентификаторы в двойных кавычках, которые не удалось разрешить в название таблицы или столбца, воспринимаются как строки. Это был осознанный выбор, сделанный задолго до того, как SQLite "выстрелил" и оказался в самых разных устройствах по всему миру, и сделан он был для обеспечения лучшей совместимости с MySQL, в то время самой популярной СУБД в мире. Сейчас я об этом выборе жалею, но избавиться от него, не ломая обратной совместимости, уже не могу.

[В Rails вроде полны решимости это поправить на своей стороне](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27782), но получится ли у них, вопрос открытый. Нельзя просто так взять и убрать кавычки у колонок в определении индекса. Это исправит именно этот баг, но добавит ограничений на то, какими могут быть имена колонок, а то и просто добавит новых багов.

---

Вы в миграции добавили **уникальный** индекс на колонку, которой не существует, `reset_password_token`. Из-за "особенности" выше в результате получился функциональный (вычисляемый) индекс по **константной строке** (`"reset_password_token"`). В результате вы не можете иметь в таблице под этим индексом больше одной строчки, потому что вставка ещё одной потребует добавления в уникальный индекс значения, которое там уже есть. Красота!

Решение сейчас — сделать новую миграцию, в которой [стереть этот индекс](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_index):

```
remove_index :users, name: :index_users_on_reset_password_token
```

Comment: Интересный перевод `mis-`...